# BusinessObjects XI 3.1 how to deploy and run the Java jar file on to the server

Tags: business-objects

I'm newbie to SAP BusinessObjects XI 3.1. I would like to run the sample Java class on the BO XI 3.1 server. When I login to XI 3.1 console, I couldn't find a way to deploy the Java class and run it on the server. My class is really simple:

```
public class BOJavaTest {
    
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Entering the Main class");
        System.out.println("Exiting the Main class");

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a jar and then publish it as a new object on the Central Management Console

1. choose the folder that you want to deploy your jar in
2. select the tab Object
3. click on New Object

The rest should be easy for you.

Things to don't forget :

in the process tab of your program, don't forget to put your main class to run.